# Windows 7 / Linux network slowness

Tags: linux, networking, windows-7

I've had Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit installed on my desktop for a week or so now, and there's one pretty big issue for me. My home network has a Centos 5.3 file server running Samba 3.0.33. Right next to it, hooked to the same switch, I've got a W2K server. So I get file transfer speeds from the W2K box to the W7 box around 1.5MB/s, while access to the Centos Box only gets 250KB/s. It's not just via Samba, either - ftp exhibits the same problem. I've tried a new NIC in the W7 box. I've tried putting the W7 hostname in the /etc/hosts file on the Centos box. I've swapped cables from the switch to the servers. None of these had any noticeable effect. Any ideas on what else to check? If I were paranoid I'd think Microsoft was sabotaging connectivity with Linux ;-)  One more thing: before installing W7, I had an XP Pro install that worked perfectly fine. I really don't think it's hardware at this point.

Comment: What hardware is on the boxes and what is your networking hardware? All of those speeds are atrocious. Since I installed Windows 7 (x64) I can get near wirespeed gigabit transfers over samba to and from my Slackware 12.2 box. It's not uncommon at all for me for network file transfers to go over 100 MB/s, and yes I mean bytes not bits.

Comment: The Centos server is a Dell Poweredge T10S. W2k is an older eMachines T2245. The W7 box is a generic AMD Athlon 64 X2 4200+. Network gear is all Linksys. I realize the eclectic collection of hardware isn't going to win any speed races, but it works for home. All I want is equivalent performance between the boxes. I've also realized it's MB/s and KB/s as edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try swapping out the switch. Hopefully you can just borrow one from a friend temporarily. Those speeds are still completely atrocious, even the 1.5 MB/s. How fast was it when you had XP Pro installed and it worked "perfectly fine" ? Even if your switch is only 100 megabits you should still get 8-10 MB/s file transfers over SAMBA, maybe even a bit closer to the theoretical max of 12.5 MB/s. You haven't explicitly said so, but I gather from what you've written so far that no possible combination of your 3 boxes yields transfers faster than about 1.5 MB/s. If this is true, this is why I think the problem is something in common between them, which would be the switch. The other thing I just thought of is maybe your switch is really old and it's only a 10 megabit switch? If that's the case do yourself a favor and spend the $10 to get a 100 mbps switch, or even a gigabit one. They're just not very expensive anymore.

Comment: I don't see how that could be the problem. I have physically unplugged the cables at each server and swapped them with no effect. In other words, the cable and switch port have no effect on the outcome. The W2K server is 6x faster every time.

Comment: The net is mostly 100megabit equipment, with one 10megabit switch I use on the rare occasions when I bring home a non-wireless capable laptop from work.

Comment: Truthfully, I don't know how fast it was with my old XP system, I just know it worked well enough not to make me notice it. I do agree, there is something wrong between them, but I suspect some net config issue.

Comment: I'm with Matt on this one. If the maximal speed you get in any combination is 1.5 MB/s, then this is a hardware issue. Unless, of course, you have manually set network adapter speeds to 10 MBPS. Check that, really! (on Linux, use `ethtool` to see configured link speed)

Comment: Please explain to me how a hardware problem with a switch is dependent on the server. I truly don't get that. Ignore for a moment the second switch port, and assume I plug port 1 into the W2K server and get 1.5MB/s. I unplug the network from the back of the server and plug it into the CentOS server and get 250KB/s. How can that be hardware? I would believe it if the results were consistent.

Comment: Switch and server do not depend on each other, of course - switch is just the most logical common bottleneck. The ultimate check: connect W7 to W2K directly, without any switches (you may need a cross-over cable for that), and measure speed. Repeat with CentOS. If your network adapters are all set to 100MBit, and you never get 6Mbytes/sec on direct connection - blame the hardware (cable and NICs). Otherwise this is indeed a software problem.

Comment: We're just saying that you're not getting anywhere near the performance you should be getting with any combination of your servers. 1.5 MB/s is definitely not "just fine." Logic would say that if there's a problem between all different servers, the thing that is in common between them (the switch) is a very likely candidate for being the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for beating me over the head with it. You prompted me to do what was necessary to find the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Matt was right. It was the switch. Here's what I found out:

I decided to take a step back because I was kinda flailing about. I downloaded [pcattcp](http://compnetworking.about.com/gi/o.htm?zi=1/XJ/Ya&zTi=1&sdn=compnetworking&cdn=compute&tm=34&f=10&tt=14&bt=0&bts=0&zu=http%3A//www.pcausa.com/Utilities/pcattcp.htm) for my windows platforms and installed [ttcp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ttcp) on my CentOS system. I then ran some tests and put them into a matrix (all numbers are KB/sec, and all hardware is 100mbps):

```
              W2K (sw)  CentOS (sw)   W7         XP
W2K (sw)         X     10200      909      1391
CentOS (sw)  11400         X      265       725
W7            7294      7287        X     10100
XP            6650      7480    10291         X
```

So, the first two boxes are on the switch in question, a Windows 2000 and a CentOS box. The XP box is on another switch while the Win7 box is plugged into the router. The boxes on the left are the senders of the data, across the top are the receivers. As you can see, and to my surprise, the results **from** boxes on the switch are horrid, while the situation **to** boxes on the switch, while not superb, are livable. The interesting part to me is the difference in speed depending on direction! Now that I have actual numbers though, I can see the problem must be on the port connected the switch to the rest of the network. So I swapped the cable to another port, and voila, the results become:

```
                W2K (sw)   CentOS (sw)         W7       XP
W2K (sw)            X         10382      6818     9531
CentOS (sw)     11095             X     11436    10560
W7               7957         11055         X    10195
XP               7281         10835      9351            X
```

Ahh, much better! While the speed still is not as fast as it should be via the switch in question, it's remarkably better. I'll be replacing the switch since it's clearly a problem child, but at least I know what's going on now.

The moral? Always Measure! I couldn't get a clear picture of what was actually happening without measuring and putting it in a form that was easy to read. The thing that was tripping me up in this case was the fact the problem was only manifested obviously in one direction (still weird to me).